# how to get distinct columns for which the rows are different

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Id     Name     site                 status
1995   sachin   http://www.abcd.co   closed
1996   sachin   http://www.abcd.co   working   
1997   sourav   http://www.abcd.co   closed
1998   sourav   http://www.abcd.co   working
```

and I want to find out which columns could vary for a given name.  In this case, for each Name, site is the same (it's always `http://www.abcd.co`), but status and Id both vary.  (I don't care about Id, but I can always throw that away afterwards.)

So for the above dataframe, if I look at "Name", I want the output "status" (or ["Id", "status"]).  By contrast, if I look at the "status" column, I'd want ["Id", "Name"] (because for status=closed, Name varies between sachin and sourav, and the Id varies as well.)

Comment: So `status` is the desired output?  Also your logic is very unclear to me

Comment: yes , logic is -- for all the group of rows where name is equal , the difference is present in status column other that Id

Comment: please post code that you have tried first

Comment: Ok, that's still not clear. Are rows always in pairs by name? how do you decide which row is closed and which is working?

Comment: you can group them when names are equal or same.

Comment: What is your expected output from this dataset?

Comment: @Shaswata: I've edited your question to try to be a little more clear.  Feel free to edit again if you don't think I've captured your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this question is as confusing as everyone seems to be finding it.  For a fixed name, we're looking for non-Id columns which vary.  I might do something like like:

```
multivalued = (df.drop("Id", axis=1).groupby("Name").nunique() > 1).any()
result = multivalued[multivalued].index.tolist()
```

which gives me

```
In [91]: result
Out[91]: ['status']
```

because

```
In [97]: (df.drop("Id", axis=1).groupby("Name").nunique())
Out[97]: 
        Name  site  status
Name                      
sachin     1     1       2
sourav     1     1       2

In [98]: ((df.drop("Id", axis=1).groupby("Name").nunique()) > 1).any()
Out[98]: 
Name      False
site      False
status     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: thanks , can you please upvote the question , all downvoted